# Assembly: using return function inside the procedure

Tags: assembly, x86, return, procedure

Is it possible to execute procedures code similar to this in assembly:

```
procedure proc near
   push bp
   mov  bp, sp
   mov  si, word ptr[bp + 4]
@@number1:
   do something and then
   jmp  @@number2
@@number2:
   do something and then
   ret
@@end
   mov  sp, bp
   pop  bp
procedure endp
```

As you can see, I would like to call `number2` part from `number1`, execute `number2` code and return to the position that I left when I jumped to `number2`.

Do you have any ideas how to do it?

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. The `@@number2` part directly follows the `@@number1` part, so there's no need to jump to it. Can you use a more realistic example?

Comment: @Michael - I am trying to find out how to jump to number2 segment from number1 inside the procedure. After jumping into number2 segment, I want to execute the code, which is in number2 segment and then I want to return to the number1 segment. I don't want to return to number1 segments beggining, I want to return to that place in which I said to my compiler to jump to number2 segment.
Maybe it is clearer now? :) I don't have written example at the time.

Comment: But why would you want to do that? The effect would be that you'd execute the `@@number2` part twice. Is that what you're trying to achive? Have you tried using the `call` instruction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... and return to the position that I left when I jumped to number2.

I guess you mean *after* you jump? if you returned to the jump you will be in an infinite loop. If so, you can use `call` rather than `jmp` as (the numbers are the order of execution):

```
procedure proc near
   push bp                   ; 1
   mov  bp, sp               ; 2
   mov  si, word ptr[bp + 4] ; 3
@@number1:
   do something and then     ; 4
   call @@number2            ; 5
   jmp @@end                 ; 8
@@number2:
   do something and then     ; 6
   ret                       ; 7
@@end
   mov  sp, bp               ; 9
   pop  bp                   ; 10
   ret                       ; 11
procedure endp
```

another way without using `call`:

```
procedure proc near
   push bp                   ; 1
   mov  bp, sp               ; 2
   mov  si, word ptr[bp + 4] ; 3
@@number1:
   do something and then     ; 4
   jmp @@number2             ; 5
@@number2_1:
   jmp @@end                 ; 8
@@number2:
   do something and then     ; 6
   jmp @@number2_1           ; 7
@@end:
   mov  sp, bp               ; 9
   pop  bp                   ; 10
   ret                       ; 11
procedure endp
```

I don't know what assembler you use, but assuming the labels are correct.